# Session less controller in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have heard about sessionles controller in MVC3.

```
 [SessionState(SessionStateBehaviour.Disabled)] 
 public class   MyController :Controller   
 { 

 }
```

If I use the sessionless controllers, then how I can browse accross the pages in my application for a particuler user? What is the best practice?

Comment: You can use also cookies or database to store some user specific information.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have a concept of a single user browsing multiple pages, a standard Session-enabled controller *is* best practice.

Controllers with session state disabled provide an optimization for controllers that do not require session state.

> By default the ASP.NET pipeline will not process requests belonging to the same session concurrently. It serialises them, i.e. it queues them in the order that they were received so that they are processed serially rather than in parallel.

http://tech-journals.com/jonow/2011/10/22/the-downsides-of-asp-net-session-state

Comment: What is the solution then for browsing accross pages for a user?

Comment: Use session state... stateless controllers are meant for situations where you do not require the concept of a session.  What problem are you trying to solve by avoiding session state?