# Why can't I browse to other pages after making an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In a legacy MVC 5 web app I want the user to be able to continue browsing after clicking a button which makes an ajax call to a long running action.

(**Note:** The action returns `void` - I am not interested in the response)

> When I click the button I am unable to make any other requests until the action completes.

**Edit:** Here is the ajax code:

```
$('#EmailReport') //
    .click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Home/EmailReport',
            complete: function() {console.log("done")},
            async: true
        });
    });
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task EmailReport()
{
   // for testing - sleep for 10 seconds
   await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
}
```

Here is a screenshot in Chrome dev tools:

[image: Ajax request]

`EmailReport` is the ajax call, the two requests at the bottom are me trying to browse to another page - as you can see the first request is `pending` and any subsequent requests are `cancelled`

Does anyone have any ideas how I can resolve or troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Rather than focus on the client, have a look at the server - does the long running action completely tie up the server while it's processing it?

Comment: Create a thread in 'EmailReport' action, which can run at background and return a HTTP 200 response. Don't wait for response via. AJAX.

Comment: it happens at local machine where IIS does not process consequent request until previous one get finished.

Comment: In the action all I am doing is sleeping for 10 seconds:

        [HttpPost]
        public void EmailReport(int id1, int id2)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }

Comment: Are you using session in that action ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494833/iis-net-only-allows-single-concurrent-response-to-given-user-session

Comment: try to use `public async Task<ActionResult> EmailReport()`

Comment: set async: false in your ajax function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be as follows :

```
Task t = new Task(() => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
t.Start();
```

It is better to use Task as compared to thread for long running jobs to avoid core affinity and better CPU utilisation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, your action waits for completion of the task. Don't make it wait and return as soon as you start the task.

```
[HttpPost]
public void EmailReport()
{
   // for testing - sleep for 10 seconds
   var myTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
   myTask.Start();
}
```

Your request is cancelled because it is a page redirect request and old page redirect requests are cancelled when a new one is issued (e.g. when you click a link 2 times, first click is ignored). It is the way browsers implement it. It is not related with the root of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I made this change but now when I look at the ajax call in dev tools network tab I am getting a 500 error?

Comment: Can you post the exception? You can find the exception in `Application_Error` method of `Global.asax` with `Server.GetLastError()`. See https://forums.asp.net/t/1926670.aspx?How+to+get+last+exception

Answer (score 0):

Use background process

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult EmailReport()
{
    Thread email= new Thread(delegate ()
   {
          generatereports();
   });
   email.IsBackground = true;
   email.Start();
   return null; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I am getting the same problem using this code

Answer (score 0):

it seems [Navigator.sendBeacon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) api will serve your purpose. it  is used to asynchronously transfer a small amount of data over HTTP to a web server. though this is an experimental technology, supported in Chrome 39+, Firefox 31+, opera 26+, there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/miguelmota/Navigator.sendBeacon) for other browsers.